# How to fix correlated subquery wrongly selected data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the 'batchid's from below table that batchid's all records 'subId' and 'substatus' in '23' and 'READY' respectively. if any values from 'subId' or 'substatus' is not matched '23' and 'READY' respectively then don't take that batch.

Table:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
| batchid |   dcn    | dcnseq | subId | substatus |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
|   10001 | 10001001 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001001 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001002 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001003 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      3 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001005 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001005 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001006 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001007 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001008 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001008 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001009 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

I am using below query to achieve this requirement.

```
select distinct batchid from fm o
where o.subId='23' and o.substatus='READY' 
and o.dcnseq='1' and o.batchid in 
(
  select a.batchid from
  (
  select i.batchid, SUM(case when i.subId='23' and i.substatus='READY' then 0 else 1 end)match from fm i 
  where i.batchid=o.batchid
  group by i.batchid
  having SUM(case when i.subId='23' and i.substatus='READY' then 0 else 1 end)=0
  )a
)
```

Result:

```
+---------+
| batchid |
+---------+
|   10001 |
|   10002 |
+---------+
```

It's working perfectly. Now changed 'substatus' value for one records as 'HOLD'

```
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
| batchid |   dcn    | dcnseq | subId | substatus |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
|   10001 | 10001001 |      1 |    23 | HOLD      |
|   10001 | 10001001 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001002 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001003 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10001 | 10001004 |      3 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001005 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001005 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001006 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001007 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001008 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001008 |      2 |    23 | READY     |
|   10002 | 10001009 |      1 |    23 | READY     |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Now result is:

```
+---------+
| batchid |
+---------+
|   10002 |
+---------+
```

Now its also working correctly. But sometimes also picking '10001' for same case. its occurred when tables have lot of batchid. I try to understand mistake. But I can't able to find out.

Answer (score 2):

I think your query is too complicated.  Just use aggregation and `having`:

```
select batchid
from fm 
group by batchid
having min(subid) = max(subid) and max(subid) = 23 and
       min(substatus) = max(substatus) and max(substatus)= 'READY';
```

I don't know if your other conditions are important.  They are in your query but not mentioned in the question.

Comment: replace selec  with select

Comment: @Gordon Bravo bro.. its perfectly working. Any idea about bug in my query?

Comment: having is not needed, `SELECT batchid FROM fm WHERE subId=23 AND substatus='READY' GROUP BY batchid`. @ArulmuruganK: Your problem remains a mystery, and is  hard to find because of not having your data..

Comment: @Luuk . . . Re-read the question.  The OP wants batches that have *only* these values.  Your approach does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting **batchid**'s where (**subid**=23 and **substatus** = 'READY'), and no other values for **subid** and/or **substatus** exist for that **batchid**.

```
select batchid 
from fm 
where subId=23 and substatus='READY' 
group by batchid
except
select batchid 
from fm 
where not(subId=23 and substatus='READY' )
group by batchid
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct f.batchid
from fm f
where not exists (
  select 1 from fm
  where batchid = f.batchid and (coalesce(subid, 0) <> 23 or coalesce(substatus, '') <> 'READY')
)
```

`coalesce()` is needed only for the case there may exist `null`s in the columns `subId` and `substatus`.
If there are not any `null`s then the where clause can be simplified to:

```
where batchid = f.batchid and (subid <> 23 or substatus <> 'READY')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b0f14d43a3bf8e9c2341ad13bb30bde).
Results:

```
> | batchid |
> | ------: |
> |   10001 |
> |   10002 |
```